# My music app dies after 7 songs are played

Tags: android

i have created an app with 16 btns,every btn plays a sound mp3.my app starts with no problem.i press and listen one mp3,two mp3...until 7 mp3...there my app forces down.i can play any mp3 i like but i can only play the 7 mp3 i click first,where is my error?

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);  
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v){
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(ClickAndPlayMusic.this, R.raw.gata);  
        mp.start();
        Toast.makeText(ClickAndPlayMusic.this, "Cat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }      

});      

        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);  
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
           public void onClick(View v){

               MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(ClickAndPlayMusic.this, R.raw.lion);  
            mp.start();                    

               Toast.makeText(ClickAndPlayMusic.this, "Lion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }

        });
```

this is the way i have created every music btn...thanks!(hope my answer is understandable)

ps:this is my logcat view when it forces down:

```
01-12 17:59:39.445: WARN/dalvikvm(16090): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7d0)
01-12 17:59:39.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16090): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 17:59:39.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16090): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-12 17:59:39.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16090):     at com.example.ClickAndPlayMusic.ClickAndPlayMusic$1.onClick(ClickAndPlayMusic.java:33)
01-12 17:59:39.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16090):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2461)
01-12 17:59:39.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16090):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8888)
01-12 17:59:39.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16090):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-12 17:59:39.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16090):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-12 17:59:39.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16090):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-12 17:59:39.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16090):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-12 17:59:39.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16090):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 17:59:39.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16090):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-12 17:59:39.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16090):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
01-12 17:59:39.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16090):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-12 17:59:39.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16090):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 17:59:39.457: WARN/ActivityManager(2796):   Force finishing activity com.example.ClickAndPlayMusic/.ClickAndPlayMusic
01-12 17:59:39.461: INFO/(2796): dumpmesg > "/data/log/dumpstate_app_error.log"
```

33 line is the mp.start(); in the onClick method of the first btn!

second logcatview:

```
01-12 19:37:39.000: ERROR/PlayerDriver(2584): Command PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE completed with an error or info -4
01-12 19:37:39.000: ERROR/MediaPlayer(20357): error (-4, -4)
01-12 19:37:39.000: ERROR/TAGNAME(20357): Prepare failed.: status=0xFFFFFFFC
01-12 19:37:39.000: WARN/System.err(20357): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.:      status=0xFFFFFFFC
01-12 19:37:39.000: WARN/System.err(20357):     at    android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
01-12 19:37:39.000: WARN/System.err(20357):     at com.example.ClickAndPlayMusic.ClickAndPlayMusic.playMedia(ClickAndPlayMusic.java:242)
01-12 19:37:39.000: WARN/System.err(20357):     at com.example.ClickAndPlayMusic.ClickAndPlayMusic.access$0(ClickAndPlayMusic.java:237)
01-12 19:37:39.000: WARN/System.err(20357):     at com.example.ClickAndPlayMusic.ClickAndPlayMusic$13.onClick(ClickAndPlayMusic.java:191)
01-12 19:37:39.000: WARN/System.err(20357):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2461)
01-12 19:37:39.000: WARN/System.err(20357):     at   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8888)
01-12 19:37:39.000: WARN/System.err(20357):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-12 19:37:39.000: WARN/System.err(20357):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-12 19:37:39.000: WARN/System.err(20357):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-12 19:37:39.000: WARN/System.err(20357):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-12 19:37:39.000: WARN/System.err(20357):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 19:37:39.000: WARN/System.err(20357):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-12 19:37:39.000: WARN/System.err(20357):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
01-12 19:37:39.000: WARN/System.err(20357):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-12 19:37:39.000: WARN/System.err(20357):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 19:37:39.008: INFO/MediaPlayer(20357): Info (1,26)
01-12 19:37:39.008: ERROR/MediaPlayer(20357): Error (-4,-4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a NullPointerException at the `mp.start()` line. That means `mp` is null at that point. Check and ensure that the resources you're trying to create the MediaPlayer with actually exist in your file structure (e.g. on `R.raw.gata`, make sure `gata` is in your raw folder, and is a valid media format).

EDIT: A couple of things you can try. I'm writing this off my head, can't compile here so you may have to make some minor modifications, but you can just work off the basic idea. The easiest way would be to just add `implements OnClickListener` to your class that's extending Activity, and then use the following code:

```
//inside onCreate()
int[] ids = {
    R.id.btn,
    R.id.btn2,
    //etc.
}

Button b;
MediaPlayer mp;

for (int i : ids) {
    b = findViewById(i);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
}

//outside of onCreate()
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn:
            if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) mp.stop();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(ClickAndPlayMusic.this, R.raw.gata);
            mp.start();
            break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) mp.stop();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(ClickAndPlayMusic.this, R.raw.lion);
            mp.start();
            break;
        //other cases here
    }
}
```

Or you could try this. I've never done it like this, but I believe it would work, and be less code. I still think the first way's preferable, just thought this would be fun:

```
int[][] data = {
    { R.id.btn, R.raw.gata },
    { R.id.btn2, R.raw.lion },
    // add all other buttons and data here
};  

MediaPlayer mp;

for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(data[i][0]);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) mp.stop();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(ClickAndPlayMusic.this, data[i][1]);
            mp.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes every file im trying to exist is in the raw folder and in mp3 format!

Comment: Is it always on the seventh button that you click, regardless of which order you click them in? Or is it specifically on button number 7?

Comment: it is always on the seventh button i click, regardless of which order i click them in

Comment: Do you actually need them all to be able to play at the same time? Or just one at a time?

Comment: i have no problem,one at a time is fine

Comment: I've added a couple ideas for you to try.

Comment: dear kcoppock,the first method you send me runs with no prob but it plays only one sound with every button i click..

Comment: Which one? Also, I don't think this is the problem, but I think `MediaPlayer mp;` should go outside of onCreate(), as a class variable.

Comment: in the second way,the for method must be outside of oncreate method?

Comment: this is for the 1rst method.yes i have moved the mediaplayer mp; outside of the on create from the beginning.i also changed this:  for (int i : ids) {
                 b =  (Button) findViewById(i);
                 b.setOnClickListener(this);
             }

Comment: with the first method,i can listen the sound of my last btn (btn16) for 2-3 time,clicking every btn,and then my app is forcing down again..

Comment: Oh, second one would go inside the onCreate() method. Oh I'm an idiot! I see the problem...add `break;` statements at the end of each `case` on the `switch` statement.

Comment: of course!!now i saw it too.i will try it right now but i m thinking that the problem has been solved

Comment: dear kcoppock may i ask you something more?if i would like to get the mp3 files from a url and not the raw folder,how would i write the path into the switch method?

Comment: You may want to post this as a separate question, I'm not sure of the answer on that.

Comment: if you could see my previous answers,i posted it tomorrow but i havent still get a clear answer.you help would be really helpfull!

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) for `MediaPlayer#create(android.content.Context, int)` states:

> When done with the MediaPlayer, you should call `release()`, to free the resources. If not released, too many `MediaPlayer` instances will result in an exception.

Whether this is the cause of you problem or not will depend on exactly the type of error you are experiencing.

**EDIT**

This is the **kind** of thing you need to do.  Having never used the `MediaPlayer` myself this may need some work on your part to make it exactly fit your needs.

```
private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
...
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);  
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v){
        playMedia("pathToCatSoundFile");
        Toast.makeText(ClickAndPlayMusic.this, "Cat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
...
private void playMedia(String songPath) {
    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(songPath);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("TAGNAME", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: so in every onclick i should call mp.release(); before every mp.start(); ??

Comment: i have tried it but it now it forces down from the first time i press a btn..obviously i m using something in a wrong way

Comment: I've not used the `MediaPlayer` before, but this [example](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-i) is reusing the same `MediaPlayer` object.  Perhaps you could use that approach rather than creating a new one each time the button is clicked?

Comment: if i write mp.release and then mp.start the app doesnt forces down but the songs are not playing,i just see the toast while clicking..

Comment: Did you read the example?  You are creating a new `MediaPlayer` each time you click the button, but the instance you create only has scope within your `onClick` method.  As in the example link, you probably need to create the `MediaPlayer` outside the `onClick`, and then handle the selection and release of the media in your `onClick`

Comment: yes but in order to know what song has to play in onClick i should create 12 mediaplayers outside the onclick and call e.x mp4 for the 4th song?

Comment: I take it you still haven't read the example I linked to?  You create **one** `MediaPlayer`, then change the file you are playing in that player in your `onClick`.

Comment: and how will i call every song in the onclick?

Comment: This would be much easier if you actually read the example I provided which goes into detail about how to do this.  However I have also edited my answer to provide an example of this kind of approach.

Comment: i have tried your edit but its not working...the app is running but when i click the btns there is no music playing!i just see the toast message.

Comment: As I said in the edit, it may need some work on your part to fit your needs.  You original code uses `R.id.XXX` to specify the media to load, my example uses a `String` of the path.  The important part is that the `MediaPlayer` is created once and reused on the button click by passing in the file you want to play.

Comment: i have posted my second logcat view as i press a btn mr dave.c!

Comment: in the onClick method for btn5 i write   playMedia("R.raw.elep");.something similar has been writen in every inClick method.is it wrong?

Comment: Yes, as I've already explained (and as is clear in the example) my code uses a `String` to the media path.  Your code uses an `int` (R.id.XXX is an `int`) to identify your file.  You can't just copy and paste my code and expect it to work immediately.  You need to try and understand it.  Try reading (a long shot I know) the links to the example and documentation.